# QGIS MySQL points import

Tags: qgis, geojson, import, database, mysql

I have a column in my MySQL database table that contains location information (GeoJSON).

I want to import this data and see the points on my QGIS project map but it doesn't seem to work.
What I was trying to do:

Layer -> Add Layer -> Add Vector Layer -> Database -> insert the server configuration -> Add -> import the relevant table.

EDIT:

I missed the query. I used the query builder and it seems to find around 200 relevant rows, but it shows only 1 point on the map. In addition, the point is not in the right spot...

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Questions here need to explain what you want to accomplish, what you tried, and what went wrong. You've only described the first two. Please [Edit] the question to describe what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Could this have something to do with coordinate reference systems (CRS)?

1. Do you know the CRS of the mySQL dataset?
2. When/after importing - did you set the CRS to the correct one?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer! It is set to the correct one